# Is the polynomial $x^{105} - 9$ reducible over $\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

> Is the polynomial $x^{105} - 9$ reducible over $\mathbb{Z}$?

This exercise I received on a test, and I didn't resolve it. I would be curious in any demonstration with explanations. Thanks!

Comment: Please make your post self-contained; I know it seems redundant, but it's best to include the actual question inside the body of the post, even if it's already in the title.

Comment: Ok, sorry! I'm newbie on this forum, and I'm learning every day on how to have a decent behavior in all aspects.

Comment: No worries, I know there are a lot of things to get used to on a new forum :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For binomials there is a classical irreducibility test (below). It implies that $\,x^{105}-c\,$ is irreducible over a field $\,F\,$ if $\,c\,$ is not a third, fifth, or seventh power in $\,F,$ since $\,105 = 3\cdot 5\cdot 7.$

**Theorem** $\ $ Suppose $\:c\in F\:$ a field,  and $\:0 < n\in\mathbb Z.$

$\quad x^n - c\ $ is irreducible over $\:F \iff c \not\in F^p\:$ for all primes $\,p\mid n\:$ and $\ c\not\in -4F^4$ when $\: 4\mid n$.

Proofs can be found in many Field Theory textbooks, e.g. see Lang's Algebra, or see Karpilovsky, [Topics in Field Theory, Theorem 8.1.6.](http://books.google.com/books?id=-2WR0fw9gLMC&pg=PA425&lpg=PA425)

Comment: @Zev Typos now fixed, thanks.

Comment: So, $x^{105}-9$ is irreducbile over $Z$ ?

Comment: Yes, since $\,9\,$ is neither a 3rd, 5th nor 7th power of a rational, the theorem implies that the polynomial $\ X^{\large 3^i 5^j 7^k}\!\!-9\ $ is irreducible over $\,\Bbb Q.\ \ $

Answer (score 7):

**Hint:** Make a [Newton polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_polygon) for the prime $p=3$. Use the corollary at the top of page 2 in [these notes by Paul Garrett](http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/number_theory/newton_polygon.pdf) (alternatively, here are screenshots: [page 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJ7Av.png), [page 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQ8Di.png)).

Comment: This is the approach I would have taken, though perhaps involving more advanced techniques than OP had at the fingertips during the test mentioned.